# Why my pointer and blue dot are not together?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers, ol3-google-maps

I am drawing features on map, using openlayers3. But my pointer and the blue dot(stroke) are not together.
I have used [this](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html) example.[image]

Comment: what's your test environment?

Comment: I am running a local nodejs server.

Comment: + web browser, OS, ..

Comment: Chrome browser, Version 57.0.2977.0 (64-bit)
OS: MAC OS Sierra 10.12.2